# SAS PROC SQL String Manipulation

Tags: char, sas, proc-sql

Can I convert a string column formatted as "YYYY-MM" from SQL back into a Date that uses text. (ie. January, 2014) as a new column using proc SQL?

Initially my source is 2014-01 and I would like every row to be converted to the respective month and year as shown. I have tried the Format option outside of the proc SQL table build, however I need it as a Macro date afterwards.

Thanks

Comment: The answer is probably yes, but you aren't really explaining yourself very well.  What is "a Date that uses text" - is that a formatted numeric column?  And when you reference SQL, is this just SAS's SQL or are you putting this in SQL Server (or getting it from there) or similar?

Comment: It's formatted that way, but is it a SAS date or a text field that is YYYY-MM?

Comment: The SQL I am referring to is PROC SQL( Only in SAS). Secondly the text format of the char to date conversion would read : January, 2014  from the original Char value of 2014-01

Comment: @Reeza The Column field YYYY-MM is a text field I want to convert to a name field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `PROC SQL` has to do with the issue of converting the value. One way would be to convert your string to date using `INPUT()` and then use the `CATX()`, `PUT()` and `YEAR()` functions and the `MONNAME.` format to build the new string.

```
data _null_;
   str='2014-12';
   date=input(str,anydtdte.);
   format date date9.;
   want=catx(', ',put(date,monname.),year(date));
   put (_all_) (=/);
run;
```

You could skip the middleman and just parse the string yourself to get the year number. This might be easier to code inside an SQL statement.

```
want=catx(', ',put(input(str,anydtdte.),monname.),scan(str,1,'-'));
```

Comment: You are spot on with the second statement and it can be used in PROC SQL. Thanks so much.

Comment: Would there be a reason the month doesnt alternate its name when its expanded to 2014-02

Comment: I think MONNAME takes the date and not the month as input. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option that uses a custom format. First convert to date using INPUT() with the ANYDTDTE. format. Then you can either display the variable with the format or you can convert it to a new character variable with the format applied.

```
/*Create your own format definition*/
proc format;
picture monyyc_fmt (default=25)
low - high = "%B, %Y" (datatype=date);
run;

data want;
   str='2014-12';
   date=input(str,anydtdte.);
   format date monyyc_fmt.;
   want=put(date, monyyc_fmt.);
   put (_all_) (=/);
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Results are:

```
                    Obs      str           date              want

                    1     2014-12    December, 2014    December, 2014
```

References for the custom date format:
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/243-31.pdf

Answer (score -1):

In SQL, consider the next example:

-- The table holding the result

CREATE TABLE #myTable(stringDate CHAR(7), dateValue DATETIME, newStringDate VARCHAR(20))

-- The values in original format

INSERT INTO #myTable(stringDate) SELECT '2014-01'

INSERT INTO #myTable(stringDate) SELECT '2014-02'

INSERT INTO #myTable(stringDate) SELECT '2014-03'

INSERT INTO #myTable(stringDate) SELECT '2015-01'

INSERT INTO #myTable(stringDate) SELECT '2015-02'
GO

-- All months have a first day, so conveting "2014-01" to date is just removing "-" and adding "01"

UPDATE #myTable SET dateValue = CAST(REPLACE(stringDate, '-', '') + '01' AS DATETIME)
GO

-- When we have the dates, you can tranform it to the format you want

UPDATE #myTable SET newStringDate = DATENAME(MONTH, dateValue) + ', ' + CAST(YEAR(dateValue) AS VARCHAR)
GO

SELECT * FROM #myTable

Comment: This is not valid syntax in SAS.

Comment: So given the only true reason i would need to alter the string YYYY-MM is for titling purposes So is it possible to alter the String macro in the title of the Proc report  using %sysfunc(left(%sysfunc(  &VariableX ,
worddate18.)))